# Can I use "aging" to describe a thing that has deteriorated from long use?

Tags: grammar, verbs

The feeding bottle has been used for a long time. It started aging. The plastic is melting and became sticky.

> The bottle is old and aging.

Does the verb "aging" describe well the quality decreasing because of using for a long time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "aged" may fit better than "aging".

"Aged" is often used to note the physical effect of being old, for people and also objects.

> The book was very old.  Its aged pages were now nearly dust.

Also, to me (native speaker) "aging" sounds active and alive, like a person. "Aged" doesn't sound this way to my ears.

If a plastic bottle is old, it may be degraded by ultraviolet rays breaking polymer bonds, often taking on a cloudier appearance.  I don't know that it would become sticky, but if it were around grease vapors in the air then these might make it sticky over time.

If the bottle has changed as a result of much use, you may also want to consider the word "timeworn".

Answer (score 0):

"Old and aging" would be *redundant*.   If you want to say the bottle is in poor condition due to its *age*, there are many other words you can use:  *deteriorating, decrepit, degraded, disintegrating, falling apart, corroding, cracking,* etc.

> The house at the end of our street is old and *dilapidated*, and looks like it's about to collapse.

Answer (score 0):

To me aging is a process. So my shoes are aging  quickly  because I wear them every day. Or another example is : "
My father is aging quickly because he has smoked all his life. Aging is the process of becoming aged.